# GEOSERVER: Login Error from different location - j_spring_security_check

Tags: authentication, proxy, reverse, geoserver

This is my firsrt post because I stuck on this problem for the last two weeks trying to understand the problem...

I installed succesfully geoserver on a windows server and a linux server. Locally everythings works fine.

Than I added a reverse Proxy on each machine (IIS and NGINX) - locally also working:
localhost "redirects" to localhost:8080/geoserver/

So when I enter "http://localhost" or the local ip address it shows the geoserver login page -FINE!

PROBLEM: When I try to login from a different machine I can access the login page. But the login fails and the displayed URL is "wrong": Connection refused

[image: screenshot1].

The same happens on Linux, so i think this must be a configuration problem in geoserser.

Actual test environments:

- Win Server2022, Tomcat 9 + IIS + GEOSERVER 2.23.2+ Adoption JDK 11
- Win Server2022, GEOSERVER MSI Installer with Jetty + IIS + Adoption JDK 11
- Linux Ubuntu + GEOSERVER BINARY + NGINX

What I have tried:

- Adding the proxy Base URL in the Geoserver GUI: Result--> I can't login on localhost anymore
- Adding the proxy Base URL in the web.xml config file: Result --> I can't reach the login page from different PC.
- Editng the CORS Settings in the web.xml file: Maybe I did something wrong, but nothing changes.
- I did not find the the CSRF thing which is mentioned in the geoserver docs.
- Disabling any firewall setting

I'm wondering why I can't get this working. It should be an "Out Of Box" process to make a geoserver accessable from any location.

Sorry for my english and if this a dumb question but I followed nearly every tutorial or thread that has to do with this proxy thing.
This video helped me a lot and I went through it step by step whith no luck.

[YOUTUBE VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gjfb4cF_j8k)

Every time during the login process from a different PC (in the same network) I receive a j_spring_security_check error in the address bar.

What I have not testet is to set up a local DNS that points to the geoserver machine. I only worked with the IP adresses.

Maybe someone can show me his working config for my needs

Thanks in Advance!
Kind regards

Comment: You need to do the "CSRF thing which is mentioned in the geoserver docs." - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html#csrf-protection

Comment: This site is for programming, your question rather belongs to serverfault.com.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation seems to be outdatet or wrong. Whether in the binary nor in the war web-inf.xml is this CSRF part. Some guys mentioned it is in the CORS section.
But this did not work for me.

I will  try it further by myself.